# Keras Tuner how to do basic grid search

Tags: python, tensorflow, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

[Keras Tuner](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/) offers several tuning strategies in the form of tuner classes. I fail to find an implementation for the most basic tuning strategy, which is a grid search. Did I oversee it? If not, is there a way to force the strategy on one of the other tuner classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RandomSearch Tuner](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/random/#randomsearch-class) can be abused to get the wanted behavior via the `max_trials` argument. Specifiying a value larger than the sum of elements in the defined hyperparamter space make the RandomSearch tuner run each hyperparameter combination once in a random order until all combinations are exhausted. The tuner will stop at that point even though `max_trials` is not exhausted and the grid search is done.